# mysql -- wampserver -- base de datos relacionadas

Tags: mysql

aclaro soy nuevo en programacion, y bueno tengo unas dudas 
estoy creando DB en mysql y tengo confusion con las relaciones de las tablas.. 
le dejo lo que hice y quiero que me indiquen si están bien relacionadas

`create database prueba;`
`use prueba;`

TABLA PAIS

```
create table pais(
 id_pais int auto_increment primary key,
 nombre_pais varchar(50) not null
)
```

TABLA PROVINCIA

```
create table provincia(
 id_provincia int auto_increment primary key,
 nombre_prov varchar(50) not null,
 idPais int not null,
 foreign key (idPais) references pais(id_pais)
 on delete cascade on update cascade
)
```

TABLA DEPARTAMENTO

```
create table departamento(
 id_departamento int auto_increment primary key,
 nombre_dpto varchar (50) not null,
 id_prov int not null,
 foreign key (id_prov) references provincia (id_provincia)
 on delete cascade on update cascade
)
```

TABLA MUNICIPIO

```
create table municipio(
 id_municipio int auto_increment primary key,
 nombre_mun varchar (50) not null,
 id_dpto int not null,
 foreign key (id_dpto) references departamento (id_departamento)
 on delete cascade on update cascade
)
```

TABLA LOCALIDAD

```
create table localidad(
 id_localidad int auto_increment primary key,
 nombre_loc varchar (50) not null,
 id_mun int not null,
 foreign key (id_mun) references municipio(id_municipio)
 on delete cascade on update cascade
)
```

TABLA BARRIO 
considero crear esta tabla porque la idea es luego poder sacar datos estadisticos de la misma

```
create table barrio(
 id_barrio int auto_increment primary key,
 nombre_barrio varchar (50) not null,
 id_loc int not null,
 foreign key (id_loc) references localidad(id_loc)
 on delete cascade on update cascade
)
```

TABLA PERSONA

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS persona (
  id_persona  int  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombre_per  varchar(100) not null,
  apellido_per  varchar(100) not null,
  numeroId  int  not  null,
  calle varchar(100) not null,
  numeroCalle  varchar(10),
  piso  varchar(10),
  dpto  varchar(10),
  lote  varchar(10),
  mzna  varchar(10),
  entreCalle  varchar(100),
  yCalle  varchar(100),
  CP  varchar(10) not null,
  cod_fijo  int(11) not null,
  fijo  int(11) not null,
  cod_celular  int(11) not null,
  celular  int(11) not null,
  id_ba  int not null,
  id_loc1 int not null,
 id_mun1 int not null,
  id_dpto1 int not null,
  id_prov1 int not null,
  id_pais1 int not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_persona),
  id_ba  int not null,
  id_loc1 int not null,
  id_mun1 int  not null,
  id_dpto1 int not null,
  id_prov1 int not null,
  id_pais1 int not null,

FOREIGN KEY (id_ba) REFERENCES barrio (id_barrio) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (id_loc1) REFERENCES localidad (id_localidad) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (id_mun1) REFERENCES municipio (id_municipio) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (id_dpto1) REFERENCES departamento(id_departamento) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (`id_prov1`) REFERENCES provincia (id_provincia) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (id_pais1) REFERENCES pais (id_pais) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

las he creado en wampserver, mi duda principal es si esta bien que los datos del domicilio esten en la tabla persona o deberia crear una tabla domicilio???

gracias!

Comment: Un domicilio puede ser ocupado por múltiples personas por lo que si en la tabla personas 5 son familia y tienen la misma dirección serían 5 registros con información repetida, **creo** que lo mejor ahi sería una relación de muchos a muchos entre personas y una tabla domicilios, por la razón antes explicada, pero igual espera aportes de otros usuarios

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, en realidad si pense en armar una tabla direccion con los campos calle, nro(PK), dpto, piso, lote, mzna, entreCalle, yCalle ... y en la tabla persona un campo direccion(FK), pero se me genera un problema ya que estoy haciendo prog en java y no se como ingresar los datos en ambas tablas... las demas tablas tengo pensado llenar JComboBox desde la BD... o por lo menos eso quiero intentar X)

Comment: Si quieres que te salga bien una base de datos y tener claro que campos van donde y que no haya dependencias, revisa las fases de normalización hasta llegar a Boyce-Codd y no tendrás problemas con eso la proxima vez

Comment: Es imposible saber si esta bien o mal sin saber tus reglas de negocio. Un domicilio puede ser habitado por varias personas? si. Pero eso no quiere decir que vas a poder unir las personas a los domicilios.. En general cada persona tiene su domicilio y por mas que se repitan es de cada persona. Por lo tanto estaria bien, siempre y cuando tus reglas dicen que tiene un solo domicilio. Y si no sabes como ingresar datos en multiples tablas, te recomendaria leer sobre eso, porque es una de las bases que necesitas para trabajar con DB. wampserver no es una base de datos. las creaste en mysql.

Comment: La clave principal esta mal. revisala. Y los delete en cascada tambien, no queres que cuando una persona borre su localidad, se le borren al resto.

Comment: gbianchi tenes razon ahora que lo indicar lo puedo ver y entender mucho mejor lo que trata el ondelete cascade, en cuanto a la clave principal no entiendo porque estaria mal (seria de todas las tablas?) lo que se me estuvo ocurriendo antes de leer fue borrar los id y dejar solo los nombre de las tablas(pais, prov, dpto, loc, mun, barrio)como PK para evitarme de esta manera hacer funciones apartes en el codigo java y que directamente muestre el nombre en la relacion (la cual la uso para llenar JComboBox) capaz esta mal nose

Comment: con respecto a donde indicas q no voy a poder unir  las personas a los domicilio es asi, ya que como tb indicas vos cada persona tiene un domicilio pero tiene fliares con el mismo domicilio asi que calculo lo dejare a eso asi.. muchas gracias me aclaraste bastante las cosas... lo que si me quedo duda es cuando mencionas que la clave primaria esta mal....